# How develop lock Android screen app that did not allow to unlock screen by other unlock app

Tags: java, android

I know how to lock a android screen , but if i install other app that unlock phone screen , so i want to  stop/prevent unlock my screen by other app in android.

if I install other app that unlock phone screen ,my app stop/prevent unlock to my screen by other app in android.

Comment: I'm sorry but your question is not comprehensible (at least to me). Please add more details/codes and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.